# Improve the model performance using MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, model

I have a dataset and want to fit a model to the data. In particular, I used three models and estimated parameters using MLE and found model (2) provides a better fit in the following picture. However, this does not provide a perfect fit. To improve the performance, what kind of strategy is effective (e.g., using a different distribution)? I use seven covariates $X$ as a linear(e.g., $\mu =\beta X, \sigma = \gamma X$) and excluding some $X$ does not change the distribution well.

(1) Normal distribution + homoscedasticity

$$f(y|X)= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y-\mu(X))^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
(2) Normal distribution + heteroscedasticity
$$f(y|X)= \frac{1}{\sigma(X)\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y-\mu(X))^2}{2\sigma^2(X)}\right)$$
(3) Weibull distribution
$$f(y|X)= \frac{k(X)}{\lambda(X)}\left(\frac{y}{\lambda(X)}\right)^{k(X)-1}\exp\left(-\left(\frac{y}{\lambda(X)}\right)^{k(X)}\right)$$

[image]

Comment: 1. Where does Weibull even fit in with all this? 2. I'm genuinely curious what you're calling a "heteroscedastic normal" when this is a univariate analysis and not regression. 3. The smoothed density is clearly platykurtic relative to the normal MLE. Use the family of 3 parameter (location, scale) T-densities with the degrees-of-freedom to fit platy kurtosis. Tukey also has a 4 parameter normal density.

Comment: your expressions for the distributions are not normalized correctly. The graphs don't look normalized either

Comment: @AdamO 1. some paper uses Weibull, so I used it, though it is a not good performance. 2. I used an approach in p.140 https://faculty.washington.edu/cadolph/mle/topic2.p.pdf. 3. If I use the scale parameter in the normal+hetero model, how do I express the pdf?

Comment: You have confused two ideas: a) using maximum likelihood to estimate model parameters (and residuals) in a linear model with non-normal errors versus b) using probability smoothers to estimate the distribution function of a univariate dataset. Your proposed methods are the former, but showing an "actual density" of residuals and overlaid density smooths are the latter.